# API Gate away Is Blocked even when CORS is enabled

Tags: axios, upload, cors, cloudinary

I'm trying to make an api to upload images to cloudinary like this

```
    fd.append('photos', file);
    fd.append('upload_preset', 
         CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET);

    axios({
        url: CLOUDINARY_API,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {

            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
        },
        data: fd
    }).then(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    })

})
```

but i recieve this error from the browser

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/******/mh/upload' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.Blockquote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to remove the three "Access-Control-Allow-*" headers from the request you are sending.

The headers Cloudinary allows for cross-origin requests don't include those headers which you are sending and therefore the browser throws this error.

Below are the headers that are allowed for cross-origin uploads (under `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`):

```
curl -sD - -X OPTIONS https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/demo/image/upload

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Cache-Control, Content-Disposition, Content-MD5, Content-Range, Content-Type, DPR, Viewport-Width, X-CSRF-Token, X-Prototype-Version, X-Requested-With, X-Unique-Upload-Id
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 19 Dec 2020 09:49:48 GMT
Server: cloudinary
Status: 200 OK
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Request-Id: d1af2a2f8a986d9ebbd1f14399dd409d
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

EDIT: In addition, Cloudinary API doesn't have a parameter called "photos". The file to upload is sent in the "file" parameter.
Therefore, you would need to replace `fd.append('photos', file);` with `fd.append('file', file);`.